# Get list of chats a bot has been invited too

Tags: slack, slack-api

I am looking at the [docs](https://api.slack.com/methods) but I don't see anything that lets me know in which channels, groups etc. my bot has been invited to.

I know there is `conversations.list` which shows me all conversations, however, I want my bot only to post in channels in which it has been invited to which is why I need to fetch that information somehow.

Am I overlooking something here?

Comment: I guess you can use `conversations.info` and check there is `isMember` equals `true`? What do you exactly mean by "in which it has been invited"? Only the channels where the bot has permissions to write in?

Comment: @HeySora  `conversations.info` seems to be an option. Although that doubles the number of requests because I'd first have to call `conversations.list`. What I mean is: After the app has been installed, I can basically post a message to all channels. I tested this by calling `conversations.list` and write a messages to all of those channels. However, I actually want to post as the _bot user_ and only in those channels, groups etc. in which the bot user is currently in.

Comment: @HeySora I have just found `users.conversations` - but it seems this one is not supported by the Java client I am using (see https://github.com/HubSpot/slack-client).

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this can be done with `users.conversations`.

In case you are using the HubSpot Slack Java Client, you can do it as follows:

```java
SlackWebClient slackWebClient = this.getSlackWebClient(accessToken);

ConversationsUserParams build = ConversationsUserParams
        .builder()
        .setConversationTypes(Arrays.asList(ConversationType.values()))
        .build();

slackWebClient
         .usersConversations(build)
         .forEach((response) -> {
             // ..
         }
```